# How to select only a single checkbox from a list of checkboxes in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, knockout.js

I have a DOM structure of the following code:

```
<tr>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox"></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label><input type="checkbox"></label></td>
</tr>
... etc
```

Using knockout.js, when I select a *single* checkbox, I want to be able to highlight *only* the parent row with a background-color. Right now, the code I've managed to implement selects *all* checkboxes and highlights *all* rows, as shown [here in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqoryb6v/1/).

It's worth noting that the number of rows I have is dynamic and could be very large, so a scaleable solution is required. I have already tried to understand the concept of [observableArrays](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) and I'm not getting far.

How can I implement the above logic using Knockout? Thanks.

Comment: A simple (but not necessarily easy-to-scale) way to do it is to have separate observables to determine when an individual checkbox is checked. See [this update](http://jsfiddle.net/eqoryb6v/2/) to your Fiddle example.

Comment: @hunch_hunch, yeah, that's probably not the most effective solution since the number of rows is dynamic and could number into the hundreds.

Comment: You'll want to use the *array* version of the [checked binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html).

Comment: @Origineil, I've seen that page and I'm having a hard time understanding it. Thanks though.

Comment: Well, here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/eqoryb6v/3/) based on your original fiddle. Without knowing more about the actual structure of the objects over which you would be iterating to create the elements, it is hard to provide a more elegant *boolean* check for applying the styling.

Comment: @Origineil I can't get your fiddle working on my code. I also don't understand how that's working or what "Without knowing more about the actual structure of the objects over which you would be iterating to create the elements" means. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this solution using an `observableArray` ([fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ianaya89/vmvtwws6/5/)):

1. I have created a **constructor** `Checkbox` method which creates **checkboxes** items.
2. Note than each checkbox has an **observable** to detect when the item **is selected**.
3. I also have an `observableArray` filled with checkboxes objects.
4. Then I only need a `foreach` **binding** to render all checkboxes that I have in the array.
5. Inside the `foreach` bind I have added **several binding** to show the **label**, to **detect** when the checkbox **is selected** and to **highlight** it if is selected.

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: checkboxes">
    <div data-bind="css: {'selected': isSelected}">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isSelected"/>
            <span data-bind="text: label"></span>
        </label>
    </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.selected {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**JS**

```
var Checkbox = function(label){
    this.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
    this.label = label;
};

var checkboxes = [new Checkbox('Item 1'), new Checkbox('Item 2'), new Checkbox('Item 3')];

ko.applyBindings({
    checkboxes: ko.observableArray(checkboxes)
})
```

It's so scaleable because you just need to add a `new Checkbox()` to the `observableArray`.